# Extract image into a file from PDImageXObject without loading it into memory

Tags: java, image-processing, pdfbox, bufferedimage, jai

This is related to [How to extract image bytes out of PDF efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60107248/how-to-extract-image-bytes-out-of-pdf-efficiently), but I'll try to restate the problem differently so it's less about PDF parsing and more about image processing.

I'm using PDFBox to extract images out of PDF files. There's an class [PDImageXObject](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.13/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/graphics/image/PDImageXObject.html) that represents the image inside the PDF, which contains image metadata (height, width, etc), and exposes two APIs to pull out the image are: `BufferedImage getImage()` and `BufferedImage getImage(Rectangle rect, int subsampling);`.

The current code is straightforward:

```
BufferedImage image = pdImage.getImage();
ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", baos);
```

However, for a large image, I'm having an issue with memory usage, as BufferedImage is storing uncompressed image data in memory, which is a lot bigger than the compressed result.

Is there a way to avoid loading the whole image into memory by breaking it up into tiles (e.g. 1024x1024) and iterating over them using the `getImage` signature that takes `Rectangle`? I'm seeing some promising information about JAI being able to use Tiles to output a compressed image without loading the uncompressed content into memory at once, but I don't understand how to tie it together with what I have from PDImageXObject. Or is there another way to do it? Is JAI still an active project?

By the way, the purpose of extracting the image is to feed it into the next component in the pipeline that can handle multiple image formats. So, if some format other than jpg, is more suited for tiled processing, that should be ok.

I'm aware of one possibility using something like [BigBufferedImage](http://jobcardsystems.com/index.php/blog/29-effective-handling-of-big-images-in-java). But I was thinking processing a Tile at a time looked promising.

Comment: `I'm having an issue with memory usage` Did you mean an exception? Or this is not what you expected?

Comment: Have you considered using `createInputStream()` and just passing on the stream to the next component or optionally putting a filter or converter in between? Then you don't need to tile anything. Or if you use `createInputStream(DecodeOptions options)` you should be able to decode just arbitrary tiles of the image. If this hint is any helpful, please let me know so I can convert it into an answer.

Comment: @kriegaex Can you explain how createInputStream() works and what DecodeOptions I pass into it? I need to get the bytes for some image format... I already have an optimization when PDImageXObject contains a JPG, but I don't know how to extract a TIFF, for example.

Comment: @hideDragon Under load, I get OutOfMemoryError. With a single file, I'm observing that a 3mb PDF file, which looks like it was produced by a scanner, loads into a 200mb BufferedImage object that serializes into a 15mb JPG file. I would like to avoid this in-memory BufferedImage.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your requirements more? Can the next service accept streams? Do images have to be converted to a certain format or can they be stored/handled as they are? E.g. can a TIFF just stay a TIFF or does everything have to be JPEG or PNG in the end? You mentioned that the PDF extractor should compress pictures. Why, if the consumer service can handle different formats as you say? Can you just stream through what you get from the PDF without any conversion or compression? Your answers determine mine.

Comment: Oh sorry, I just followed the link to your first question and read the explanation there. You tried `createInputStream()` already and a PDFBox expert (maintainer?) even told you that it works well for JPEG files (actually only with RGB colour space, not CMYK), but is not a general solution for other image formats and there is nothing out of the box. See also [this sample class from `org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox-tools`](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/tools/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/tools/ExtractImages.java?view=markup&sortby=date#l363).

Comment: I don't have a generic solution for all image formats either.

Comment: You should just run a tool that extracts the images (such as [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pdfimages)).

Answer (score 0):

OK,  I found a libray: [Commons Imaging](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/). Class [Imaging](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/apidocs/org/apache/commons/imaging/Imaging.html) maybe can help you.

I think you can try `createInputStream()` method, find out the size of real data(bytes length).